# Google SDK API Error 403 when using complete API privileges

Tags: api, permissions, provisioning

We have built a provisioning with google SDK API to create and update employees in google workspace.
We are using a service user without a role and authentication using one of the admin users.

There is an issue, when the **admin** account we are using is set with **COMPLETE API Privileges** and in the user payload we are sending   **“suspended”: true** we are getting an error back from google “403   “Not Authorized to access this resource/api” “.

If we change the admin account to **SUPER ADMIN** its working correctly and we are not getting an error.

We have tried cloning the Super Admin permissions, and set the admin account with the cloned permission yet again we are getting the same error.
Can anyone assist with understanding why its happening or how to overcome this issue?